# ActiveMQ HTTP transport protocol not able to create ActiveMQSession on Java 8

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I was using ActiveMQ 5.9.0 using HTTP transport protocol with Java 7. After I migrate from Java 7 to Java 8, my producer program is not able to create session to the broker. It keeps on trying to get the `ActiveMQSession`.

Comment: You should include the code you have for creating the session so people can attempt debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That version is very old and likely will have several issues with Java 8 not just in HTTP transport but other areas as well.  The version of Jetty used in that broker is definitely not Java 8 compatible, you need to move to the latest release v5.14.2 which should work under Java 8 although the official Java 8 supported broker is the next major release v5.15.0

Comment: I tried to use activemq latest release v5.14.2. As a standalone programs my broker,producer and consumer are working fine. When i deploy my application on tomcat 7 it is giving error "javax.servlet.ServletException: Not running on Jetty, JSR-356 support unavailable
 at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.deploy.WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.onStartup(WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.java:146) ~[activemq-jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar:9.2.13.v20150730]
".

Comment: Please help me on the above dependency issue

Comment: Exclude the (transitive) dependency `jetty-all` that comes with `activemq-http` (or whatever ActiveMQ dependency you have)